# Query attribute name together with its class

Tags: python, string, class, magic-methods, classname

The name of an attribute can be asked with `__name__`. However, I also want to inquire about the class name:

```
class Test:
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b']

print(Test.a.__name__) # → 'a' but wanted 'Test.a' or only the class 'Test'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want `__qualname__`.

```
class Test:
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b']

Test.a.__qualname__
# gives 'Test.a'
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/

> Is there also a magic method of getting the class name only?

You can get the class itself via `Test.a.__objclass__`. So the name of the class would be available via

```
Test.a.__objclass__.__name__
# gives 'Test'
```

Comment: ah thank you! Is there also a magic method of getting the class name only?

Comment: Yes: I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for both solutions! Just want to point out that `__objclass__` is less flexible than `__qualname__`, in particular is not supported by functions